# How to encode a Stream

Tags: c#, stream, xss

I have recently had an audit of my code that determined a few cross-site scripting vulnerabilities. A couple of the vulnerabilities involve using "Stream.Write". I have provided an example below, I assume the line in question will need to be encoded somehow but I'm at a loss for how to do it. Any suggestions?

```
public class EncryptedStream : Stream
    {
        private Stream dataStream;

        private void MoveToOffset(long newPosition, bool forceRefresh)
        {
            // XSS vulnerability
            this.dataStream.Write(this.contentBuffer, 0, this.contentBuffer.Length);
        }
    }
```

A few of the others look similar to this:

```
public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        // vulnerability
        compressedStream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
    }
```

Comment: How can this be an XSS vulnerability? There is no site, and there is no script? These look more like potential buffer-overflows, which are of course not possible in C#..

Comment: It's unclear to me how a `Stream` class can be suspectible to a cross site scripting attack, it just the infrustructure, a "tunnel" which delivers the content from one side to another. Your vulnerability must lie within the `this.contentBuffer` which contains unsantizied values. You must find the point in your application where there's this user input coming in, and santize it *there*. Doesn't make much sense to me to HTML-entity encode the `this.contentBuffer` in this line regardless of what's transmitted.